# Same problem... Magento Admin Sidebar menu is broken and have not being able to fix it

Tags: sidebar

I have followed all responses to the issue posted on this Blog but still unable to fix the web Admin Sidebar...
any other ideas?
[image]

Comment: update your question with a screenshot. my guess is related to static content. You should redeploy static content but before deleting that from pub/static and var/view_preprocessed